# JQuery UI Dialog iFrame Content Empty

Tags: iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

So this is an odd one.
I have inherited a page containing a JQuery UI Dialog which displays an iFrame.
The dialog opens correctly in Chrome, IE 10 / IE 10 With Compatibility Mode ON. However, some users are reporting an issue on IE 11 With Compatibility Mode ON where the dialog opens but it's content is not displayed.
I have tested with IE 11 and Compatibility Mode ON and it works fine for me but the issue still occurs for others.

The site requires Compatibility Mode to be ON, as a test Compatibility Mode was disabled and the dialog content appeared but the rest of the site suffered.

I tried forcing compatibilty mode off in the page that is the content of the iFrame in the dialog.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

(directly after /title) but that didn't help.
There was css on the dialog creation with style="display:hidden" which I removed but that didn't help.

Here is the dialog code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.dia').live('click', function() {
            var url = this.href;
            var dialog = $("#dialog");
            dialog.empty();
            dialog.append($("<iframe />").attr("src", url).attr("frameBorder", "0")).dialog({
                modal: true,
                height: 600,
                width: 450,
                title: 'Dialog',
                close: function() { window.location.reload(); }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function closeIframe() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

JQuery 1.4.2

JQuery UI 1.8.2

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Have you found a way to resolve this? We have a very similar issue in our project.

Answer (score 0):

So far my solution is to set the default `src` of the `iframe` to "about:blank" and in the jQuery dialog `open` method set the attribute to the real value. This way, for some reason the url loads normally even in IE 11.